# Есть ли готовые решения для загрузки и обработки видеофайлов на Codeigniter?

Tags: видео, ffmpeg, codeigniter, upload

Есть ли готовые решения для загрузки и обработки видеофайлов на Codeigniter?
Нигде не смог найти оптимального решения, желательно обработка видеофайлов в ffmpeg

Comment: Я зная что библы не нужны. Я имел ввиду готовый класс(контролер) с моделью и выводом :-)

Answer (score 1):

Юзаю ffmpeg на codeignter, не нужно там не какою библиотеку... там же и так все делаешь через класс и методы.... если есть вопросы задавайте..